# Cannot bind array to list using AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using an AJAX call to try and bind an array within an array to a list in C#. The second collection is always null.

---

If you are unfamiliar with DataTables just worry about the AJAX section of `dataTableOptions` as it's the same as jQuery. Here is what I have so far:

**`JavaScript`**

```
var dataRows = [{ RowCells: ["Test", "Test"] }];
var reportSectionContents = { DataRows: dataRows };
dataTableOptions = {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax:  {
        url: "/Data/ProcessDataTable",
        type: "POST",
        data: reportSectionContents
    }
};
```

**`Action`**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ProcessDataTable(ReportSectionContents reportSectionContents)
```

**`ReportSectionContents`**

```
public class ReportSectionContents
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReportRow> DataRows { get; set; }
    public ReportRow TotalRow { get; set; }

    public ReportSectionGraphContents Graph { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ReportSectionContents> LoopContents { get; set; }
}
```

**`ReportRow`**

```
public class ReportRow
{
    public IList<string> RowCells { get; set; }
}
```

When this is run the `reportSecionContents` object in the action is populated and the `DataRows` property has 1 item in the collection, which is expected. That item has an instance of `ReportRow` but within that object the `RowCells` property is always null.

I expected this to be populated with 2 string items (`"Test"`, `"Test"`). What am I missing?

**EDIT**

With arserbin3's answer I was able to get a bit further but now I am receiving an error with my AJAX request which is "Invalid JSON primitive: *followed by the JSON string*". I've tested this out using just standard jQuery AJAX and it works fine so I'm pretty sure that this is a DataTables issue now (www.datatables.net). The string I am passing across seems to be incorrect but the information that datatables is trying to parse seems to not like being in JSON form

Comment: I am curious if IList<> might be causing the issue. I have run into issues with IList<> not properly being mapped while working in EF in certain situations. Have you tried hanging IList to just List?

Comment: I have tried just List and it was the same result. Perhaps that would cause the same problem? Edit: Just tried changing it to a collection and I still have the same problem

Comment: Have you added 
    dataType: 'json'
to the ajax call to see if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

You should only stringify the parent object that is set as the 'data' attribute value of the AJAX request.
Also, you should setting the `contentType` as JSON, so it makes the request properly as `application/json`.

Change your JavaScript code to this:

```
var dataRows = [{ "RowCells": ["Test", "Test"] }];
var reportSectionContents = { DataRows: dataRows };
dataTableOptions = {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax:  {
        url: "/Data/ProcessDataTable",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(reportSectionContents)
    }
};
```

Comment: fixed. RowCells should be in quotes. You can verify valid JSON at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I'm still getting the same error although I'm suspicious whether this is a DataTables issue. in jsonlint I get the message Parse error on line 1:
0=%7B&1=%22&2=d&3=a&
^
Expecting '{', '['

Answer (score -1):

You need to surround the array of strings with JSON.stringify(). This will make it properly convert an array of strings into an array of strings. It is coming to the server as a form value of "Test, Test" instead of a proper array.

```
var dataRows = [{ RowCells: JSON.stringify(["Test", "Test"]) }];
```

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? This works too. You can either stringify the whole thing or just the array. This is still a valid answer.